# How to add and unstring javascript syntax each object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i have this data

```
const data = [ 
  { date: '2018-04-11T00:00:00.000+07:00',
    price: 5000 },
  { date: '2018-04-03T00:00:00.000+07:00',
    price: 2000 } 
]
```

i'm trying to add moment.js syntax to date format, the expected output is:

```
const data2 = [ 
  { date: moment('2018-04-11T00:00:00.000+07:00').format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
    price: 5000 },
  { date: moment('2018-04-03T00:00:00.000+07:00').format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
    price: 2000 } 
]
```

This is my code. unfortunately, moment also in String.

```
const map = data.map(el => `moment(`+el.date+`).format('DD/MM/YYYY')` )
```

The output

```
["moment(2018-04-11T00:00:00.000+07:00).format('DD/MM/YYYY')", "moment(2018-04-03T00:00:00.000+07:00).format('DD/MM/YYYY')"]
```

My purpose is to format an array from client body to create a Mongodb object, here's the code

```
const newPurchases = new Purchases({
  date: moment(req.body.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
  price: req.body.price
})
newPurchases.save((err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err
  res.json(data)
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just remove all the template literal backticks..  Your just creating a string of code otherwise.  eg.. `data.map(el => moment(el.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'))`

Comment: Thank you, it's worked. my bad that i thought before that's not possible while i'm using chrome console

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the template literal backticks.